# Trying to test my android application on firebase test lab but it keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, firebase

hope everyone is doing well.

I am trying to test my application on firebase however it keeps crashing. Firstly, I tried to test it and got the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.leonapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.leonx.application-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.leonx.application-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

After doing some research I found out about Multidex and configured my app towards this however after trying to test it again, I get a new error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.leonx.application-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.leonx.application-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.leonx.application-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Does anyone have any advice on how to tackle this? App is running fine on the emulator and on my phone. I have also cleaned the project however still getting the above error

Many thanks, Leon

Comment: Multidex is handled differently [depending on API](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l).  Is your Test Lab configuration for the same API level as your local emulator and device?  You say the app runs without error on those.

Comment: @bob thanks for replying, I just tried running the Test lab now using the same api's as the emulator and phone however i am still getting the same crash message as before